# Add query to anchor tag

Tags: wordpress

I'm simply trying to create a link to a page, and I am attempting to pass a **key/value** along with the request:

```
<a href=http://example.com?id=2075> Go to a page </a>
```

Here is my code

```
<?php
  $my_url = add_query_arg( 'id', the_ID(), 'http://example.com' );
  echo $my_url;
?>

<a href="<?php echo site_url('/some-page?id=' . the_ID()); ?>">Go to some page</a>
```

The echo above outputs the following:

```
2075http://example.com
```

How do I pass a parameter to a page?

Comment: replace `the_ID()` with `get_the_ID()`. the_ID() is similar to `echo get_the_ID()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `the_ID()` incorrectly. This function directly echos the output. So, you need to use `get_the_ID()`.

```
<?php
$my_url = add_query_arg( array( 'id' => get_the_ID() ), home_url( '/some-page/') );
?>

<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $my_url ); ?>">Go to some page</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `the_ID()` documentation here: 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_id/

You will see that it does `echo get_the_ID()`

Your problem is that you are echo-ing the output rather than concatenating it in the string.

So, doing

```
<?php
  $my_url = add_query_arg( array( 'id' => get_the_ID() ), home_url() );
?>

<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $my_url ); ?>">Go to some page</a>
```

Would fix your issue

Also, make sure you understand the difference between `site_url()` and `home_url()` before choosing to use one of the two: [What's the difference between home_url() and site_url()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20294/whats-the-difference-between-home-url-and-site-url)